# Session Resets when uploading a file using a flash plugin

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, session-variables

My session is getting reset after I upload file using a flash plugin.  I put some logging into the Session_Start function and I see its called every time I upload a file using the flash plugin.  I'm not sure what would be causing this. This is working locally for me in dev environment with the same server and settings.

I'm using 
IIS 7 with Windows Server 2008 R2.

My app:
ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.0 (legacy app)

I upload other files on the site without the flash plugin and those work.  This functionality worked before.  But for some reason now it stopped working.

Any ideas on what could be causing this to occur?

Comment: Is your issue solved?If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First Microsoft End of support for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

The default server configuration does not allow you to upload files with Flash Uploader.

You could try below settings:

**1)Disabling Request Validation:**

ASP.NET automatically validates a request or rejects it if there are dangerous fields. However, HTML5/Flash Uploader sends files data in text fields (instead of binary ones) due to Adobe Flash Player limitations. IIS may treat this behavior as potentially dangerous and, thus, you can get the following error during uploading:

A potentially dangerous Request. Form value was detected from the client

use below code to disable the request validation on the page which processes the upload request:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

**2)Assign permission:**

The folder where you are going to save files should have modified permissions. 
Assign the iis_iusrs and iusr or application pool identity full permission to the upload folder.

**3)Configuring Maximum POST Request Length:**

Usually, the limitation for maximum POST request length is specified to reduce the risk of DoS attacks. If the request size exceeds a specific value, it is considered malicious and the upload would be broken.

If you are going to upload files larger than the default limitation, increase the latter.

Go to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and change

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

To

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

add below code in your application web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="2147482624" /> <!-- in bytes -->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/> <!-- in kilobytes -->
</system.web>
```

**4)Configuring Control to Support Medium Trust Level:**

.NET Trust Level in IIS specifies the level of code access security for ASP.NET applications. By default, HTML5/Flash Uploader works under the full trust level. However, if you create a website with the medium trust level on your server, you should configure HTML5/Flash Uploader to support this level as well. To perform this, just set the MediumTrustCompatibility property to true as the snippet below shows:

```
<aur:ImageUploaderFlash ID="ImageUploaderFlash1" runat="server" 
    MediumTrustCompatibility="true">
</aur:ImageUploaderFlash>
```

Setting the MediumTrustCompatibility property to true requires an application's pool to be routed to a single worker process. To perform this run IIS Manager, choose the application pool under which your website works, click Advanced Settings in the Actions panel, and set Maximum Worker Processes to 1:

[image]